# How do I configure a WebSecurityContext with filters that depend on other beans with Spring Security?

Tags: spring, spring-security

How do I configure a WebSecurityContext with filters that depend on other beans with Spring Security?

I am creating a plugin support for our authentication service, and that's what I am trying to do:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(1)
@ComponentScan(includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = AuthPlugin.class))
public class AuthPluginSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterAfter(new AuthPluginFilter(), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Now, my `AuthPluginFilter` will of course depend on other beans, the implementations of the plugin, for example.

But this wouldn't work, as `configure` is overwritten from `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```java
    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http, List<AuthPlugin> authPlugins) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterAfter(new AuthPluginFilter(authPlugins), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class);
    }
```

I can think of workarounds with `@Autowired` annotations at the fields. But I'd like to avoid this, if possible.

Is there a more beautiful, recommended way of doing this?

Comment: Just define the `AuthPluginFilter` as an `@Bean` so it is managed by Spring.

Comment: How do I inject it then in `configure`?

Comment: Just autowire them in your class

Comment: That's what I'd like to avoid, as written above. I really would like to use constructor autowiring and not field autowiring.

Comment: Reading is an art. I nowhere said you should change your filter. You should autowire your filter into your configuration class. Which can be constructor or field whatever you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want the list of plugins, just inject them into your security config. Then use that list in the configure method to construct the filter.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(1)
@ComponentScan(includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = AuthPlugin.class))
public class AuthPluginSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final List<AuthPlugin> plugins;

    public AuthPluginSecurityConfig(List<AuthPlugin> plugins) {
      this.plugins=plugins;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterAfter(new AuthPluginFilter(this.plugins), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class);
    }
}
```